Employment Law, Gender Discrimination for Male Servers
I work at a fairly large restaurant chain in Alberta, Canada (they have locations across both Canada and USA) as a male server/waitress. Servers are paid often the same base wage of $15/hour with tips included that deviate per shift.
The restaurant is divided into two major areas, namely the Dining room and the Lounge, where you are scheduled in only one for the entirety of your shift. Upper management has told me (with witnesses involved) that male servers are barred from serving in the Lounge, whereas female servers are allowed to serve in both the Dining room and Lounge. Here, managements rationale for this is that the clientele in the Lounge would prefer a female server rather than a male (which in my opinion is doubtful, except for the occasional customer, since this is not a restaurant that is based off of sex appeal like Hooter's for example). Now, the problem is, Lounge shifts yield often more than double the tip income (due to more traffic/sales) and are considered the best shifts to have.
This restaurant doesn't seem to operate under a "bona fide occupational requirement" as would some restaurants/bars such as Hooter's or stripclubs would. Is this gender discrimination and illegal to do? I read somewhere (however might not be Alberta law, rather someplace else) that customer preferense alone does not qualify as a suitable defense for BFOQ, hence is illegal. If this is true, what actions should be taken (if any) and is it worth while to make a complaint to the Alberta Human Rights Commission?
As a side note, these complaints have been heard multiple times from various male servers from upper management for over a year now without remedy.
Hopefully someone has an answer for this, would really appreciate it, and thank you!

Hooters isn't BFOQ, they are just very quick to settle allegations to never have a verdict against them.

I have heard this actually, reading into it more. Curious if there is a distinction made between Hooters where they only hire female servers, versus a different restaurant that hires both male and female servers, but only allows female servers to take certain shifts (the better paying ones in terms of time on and tips) however? Especially when it is outright said by upper management the gender of the person is the reason after hiring.

the difference is that hooters is in plain violation and just pays off people that sue.

@Trish Is Hooters in violation of Civil Rights Act

@Themathgod I could see the difference in the customer expectation. If I were to attend an establishment with Hooters I would choose an establishment with Hooters of my preferred gender. That is part of what I want as a customer. If I go to a restaurant, I predominantly go there for the food, the server/ waitress is just an afterthought.

Well, they do not refuse to employ you (which would be illegal discrimination). They refuse to give you a certain kind of shifts — which is not an employment but merely business operational decision.

I see, however businesses can make operational decisions with reasoning based soley off gender, where one gender is given a benefit over the other, which I've read is also illegal. The benefit in this case being shifts that generate the most tips/pay the most. The question here I guess is... would these shifts constitute a benefit towards that gender?

The argument made in favor of Hooters is that they're not just a restaurant, they're also an entertainment venue. So hiring only female wait staff is like a strip club only hiring strippers of a particular gender.
